# How to get Google Ads impressions based on location

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I am working with Google Ads API. Based on my use case, I need to get the impressions, clicks, and other statistics about the products based on location(Without creating the campaign).
[image: Impressions according to the location]

I contacted the Google Ads API team to address the issue but the doc reference they provided me didn't work in my case. (I'm not using keywords also)

1. [generate forecast metrics](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-forecast-metrics?hl=en)

And also the query I used to access the data is...

```
public void queryTest(long customerId,String campaignId) {
    try (GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsServiceClient =
                 googleAdsClient.getLatestVersion().createGoogleAdsServiceClient()) {
        SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest request =
                SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setCustomerId(Long.toString(customerId))
                        .setQuery("SELECT metrics.clicks, metrics.impressions,geographic_view.country_criterion_id FROM geographic_view WHERE geographic_view.country_criterion_id = 1009919")
                        .build();

        ServerStream<SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse> stream =
                googleAdsServiceClient.searchStreamCallable().call(request);

        for (SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse response : stream) {
            for (GoogleAdsRow googleAdsRow : response.getResultsList()) {
                System.out.println("outPut"+googleAdsRow.getGeographicView());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue??
Thank you!!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What happens when you run that code?

Comment: Thank you for your response I'm getting this kind of response. 
Method: google.ads.googleads.v10.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream, Endpoint: googleads.googleapis.com:443, CustomerID: 1673682197, RequestID: 8sc_yhslDcjHh1mrvmrsGw, ResponseCode: OK, Fault: null 
But I need metrics.impressions, metrics.ctr properties